# How to make sure that link isn't broken using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Suppose, following is the html code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

By following code, I can make sure that href is intended for the link:

```
expected_href = "http://www.google.com"
actual_href = driver.find_element(:tag_name, "a").attribute("href")

unless actual_href == expected_href
  puts "Link is incorrect"
end
```

But I want to make sure that link "http://www.google.com" isn't broken means if I make request to "http://www.google.com" it's response should be with status "200"

How can I test this? Is there any Ruby library to test http requests?

Comment: `broken` means what? Need more info for the same.

Comment: I want to test this without opening that link (means avoiding click on link). Make request to that url using some Ruby libraries, take it's response & check response has status=200

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [`URI doc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract)

```
require 'uri'

expected_href = "http://www.google.com"
actual_href = "http://google.com"
uri1 = URI(actual_href)
uri2 = URI(expected_href)
puts "Link is incorrect" unless [uri1.host,uri1.scheme] == [uri2.host,uri2.scheme]
#=> Link is incorrect
```

Or you can look here for other ways[`Net HTTP get source code and status`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298281/net-http-get-source-code-and-status)

Comment: Your above code doesn't make request to url & hence can't get status of it. But the links you pointed to are very helpful. Using those links, I could solve the problem. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Humm there are multiple ways to solve the problem you have and I gave you all the possible way I know. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

expected_status = ["200", "OK"]

link = driver.find_element(:tag_name, "a").attribute("href")
io = open(link)
link_status = io.status

unless expected_status == link_status
  puts "Link is broken"
end
```

Comment: This is not Good in this community. You are just duplicating the answer I have given to you. probably you can put this in your post as an **EDIT**.

Comment: The question is how to you check the return status using selenium-webdriver? Giving a solution using `open-uri` doesn't answer the question.